# Remove some files from past commits in Hg

Tags: mercurial

I have some audio files (for testing purposes) in my project and I thought it's more convenient for other teammates if I just include them in the Hg repo. After pushing to the server, I find them taking too much space and time to download. Is there anyway to remove those files? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general overview about changing the history in Mercurial, see [Editing History](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory) in the Mercurial wiki.

The fact that you have already pushed to the server [makes the whole thing a bit more complicated](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory#Consequences_of_editing_history) (the problem would be easier to solve if the changes were in your local repository only).

You can use [the Mercurial Queues extension to **really** remove the changes from the history](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory#Editing_recent_history_with_MQ).